# Performance of PostgreSQL two joins and NOT EQUAL clause between them

Tags: postgresql, join, query-performance

Basically we have a fact table (in reality it is partitioned and have pretty wide structure) - transactional table, static once transaction is loaded and never changes IDs which it has, and there we have two fields that are IDs of the same dimension (this dimension's attributes can change time to time).
And we need to query all the records from the fact table that do not have same "name" in one line from dimensional table.
How we can achieve the best performance there?

#### Additionally:

- Both fact and dimensional tables are populated on scheduled basis, so if we can improve the performance adding some mapping tables - this can be done
- Indexes, arrays, compound indexes - whatever
- PostgreSQL 10 (if there is something in 11 and 12 that can help - advises are appreciated)
- Code is below

Any ideas on how to restructure this to obtain same result faster - would appreciate.

#### Fact table

```
select 
    generate_series as row_id
    ,(random()*1000000)::bigint as id1
    ,(random()*1000000)::bigint as id2
into table_fact
from generate_series(1,10000000);
```

#### Dimension table

```
select 
    generate_series as row_id
    ,'Dimension #' || (random()*10000)::bigint as dim
into table_dim
from generate_series(1,1000000);
```

#### The query

```
select
     tf.row_id
    ,tf.id1
    ,tf.id2
    ,td1.dim
    ,td2.dim
from table_fact tf
left join table_dim td1 on tf.id1=td1.row_id
left join table_dim td2 on tf.id2=td2.row_id
where not (td1.dim = td2.dim);
```

Comment: Using your setup script, almost every row in table_fact gets returned.  (In my execution of it, only 12 get omitted).  Is that going to generally be the case?

Comment: Are these table_fact{id1,id2} fields supposed to refer to the dimension table? In that case, they should be Foreign Keys. Also, to make sense,  table_dim.dim will probably need to be unique (and NOT NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be fine, because you should have indexes on the appropriate dimension columns.  But `left join` doesn't seem appropriate because you require a match.  So:

```
select tf.row_id , tf.id1, tf.id2, td1.dim ,td2.dim
from table_fact tf join
     table_dim td1
     on tf.id1 = td1.row_id join
     table_dim td2 
     on tf.id2 = td2.row_id
where td1.dim <> td2.dim;
```

Because you need both names from both dimensions, I think you need to scan `table_fact`.

Comment: Well, yes, the query itself is OK, but its performance is not as I'd like it to be.
The query you proposed has absolutely the same execution plan and in my environment same 35 seconds on proposed data set. 
My main question is on another: How this all, the whole setup, can be improved to improve the performance.

Comment: @DenysSmakovskyi  . . . It is hard to make optimize comparisons between different columns.  You could put a flag in the fact table indicating if the two names are the same and include that flag in indexes.  You probably don't want an index just on a boolean column, because it is not very selective.

Comment: column would help, but dimension table time to time can change. In this case I can't put such column in fact table as fact table should have no updates ever.